# Memory leak with Android Application

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I was using eclipse memory analyzer for detecting memory leaks in my android application.
I wanted to remove memory leak after closing the application. I saw one object which had its instance alive even after closing the application. I checked what are the incoming references for this object instance. Are these references which could not get destroyed is the reason for the object instance being alive? If yes how can I remove it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about memory issues with android. When you close your app, it doesn't kill everything right away. It will get killed when it needs the resources.

Comment: But why didn't get garbage collected? It's because of weak reference right? And it was due to bad coding that weak reference was still there...isn't it? I want to understand where is the root cause?

Comment: @Rob Massive understatement! Memory is a very big issue in Android considering we have far less of it available than we usually have on other platforms. Beware of static references to `Context`s and zombie threads.

Comment: Android OS decides when apps are removed from memory. You do not have control over it. This is not an indication of a memory leak.

Comment: @Che, I guess I put it odd. Don't worry about memory issues after you close your app, android does that for you.

Comment: @Peter: Agreed we don't have control over the objects to get removed. But they get garbage collected after some time which is not happening in my case. So looks like memory leak